# Gradient descent method with random perturbation

Tags: reference-request, stochastic-calculus, gradient-flows

Suppose there is a function $f:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$.  One way to find a stationary value is to solve the ODE $\dot x = - \nabla f(x)$, and look at $\lim_{t\to\infty} x(t)$.

However I want to consider a variation of this method where we solve
$$ dx = - \nabla f(x) dt + C(t,x) \cdot dW_t ,$$
where $C(x,t) \in \mathbb R^{n\times n}$, and $W_t$ is $n$-dimensional Wiener process, with some kind of condition like $C(x,t) \to 0$ as $t\to\infty$.  The hope is that it might converge to a stationary value faster, and also that the stationary value it converges to will be a local minimum.

Can anyone give me some resources for where I could read about this sort of thing?  Using a google search, and following references, I did find the book 
*Random perturbations of dynamical systems* by Mark I. Freidlin and Alexander D. Wentzell, but I didn't find "gradient descent" in the index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Freidlin & Wentzell and its community is interested in a set of topics a little bit different from yours (metastability and exit problems). Your kind of cases have been studied, see for example http://repository.ias.ac.in/1132/1/323.pdf and its reference for further information.

In a nutshell, the sde you describe, under general conditions for $c$ and in the case $c$ does not depend in time, has an invariant measure proportional to $e^{ - f(x)/c }$ ( I might be missing some constant in the exponent), so as $c$ tends to zero, the diffusion converges to one of the global minimums of the function f.

Now, for the case you are interested in, where $c$ is time dependent, it is expected that the same behavior holds if $c(t,x) \to 0, \text{ as } t \to \infty$. This was studied for the case $c(t) = 1/( c_0 \log t )$, and the same result follows for $c_0$ large enough, this process is called the annealing process. The last result I have seen in this direction is given here http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aoap/1043862427. I recommend you to read the review paper http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/store/10.1002/wcms.31/asset/31_ftp.pdf;jsessionid=4CD5D404F2C4C556D5C3F4B6331C71CA.f01t02?v=1&t=idf23s2i&s=61e6eec769b556097ae3239bc68798fa9231d8c1 for a related setting that might interest you.

Comment: Thanks for the great references.  I am unable to access the last link.  Can you give me the reference to the last paper in terms of Journal, volume, title, authors, etc?

Comment: its called metadynamics by Barducci, Parinello and Bonomi.

Answer (score 1):

Not directly your question, but
Wales, [Energy landscapes](http://books.google.com/books?isbn=0521814154) (2003, 681p)
might be interesting.
That leads to "basin-hopping", a *practical* stochastic algorithm for minimizing e.g.
configurations of molecules.
[scipy basinhopping](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.basinhopping.html)
says

> The acceptance test used here is the Metropolis criterion of standard Monte Carlo algorithms,
>   although there are many other possibilities

(By the way, for accelerated gradient descent in general
see Nesterov momentum, Adagrad, Adadelta ... more methods than test cases.)